# How to configure multiple symfony2 projects (dev enviroment) on the same server

Tags: php, apache, symfony, vhosts

I do not use a cache and still I get the [same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480257/classnotfoundexception-on-multiple-symfony2-projects-in-the-same-host/27374326#27374326) in the dev enviroment.

I have three different projects that I want to run locally (dev pc Ubuntu) for development. Does anyone have a tip for me, how do I configure the vhosts or projects?

Thanks fralex

Comment: Vhosts for apache can be added individually and define the appropriate parameters for each host within each file, e.g. the document root and the hostname that should be expected, e.g. dev1.localhost, dev2.localhost etc. You can store them in /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/eachvhosthere.conf - ensure they are .conf extensions. Check syntax using `httpd -t` in console. Suggest you Google how to use vhosts in apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of Symfony2's vhost for the lastest versions of Apache (set one for each of your sites):

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/my-app.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app.local.fr
    DocumentRoot /home/me/Workspace/MySymfonyApp/web

    <Directory /home/me/Workspace/MySymfonyApp/web>
            Options Includes FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride none
            Require all granted
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my_app_error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my_app_access.log vhost_combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Active it with the command:

```
$ sudo a2ensite my-app
```

And reload Apache's service:

```
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```

Do not forget to active url rewriting (you have to do this only once, not for all vhosts)!

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: How can I use for app_dev.php?
Sorry for this maybe stupid question, but I'm confused. I have already tried various settings before I asked the question.

Comment: With this configuration, if you use the url `http://my-app.local.fr/api` this will be replaced with `http://my-app.local.fr/app.php/api`. If you want to use `app_dev.php` just call the url `http://my-app.local.fr/app_dev.php/api`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it today with Symfony 2.6.1.

Comment: Tell me if you have a problem.

Comment: This is the solution. Now it works as I have imagined. Thank you.